# Can restarting a router result in its software being updated?

Tags: malware, router, internet, patching, isp

Articles in the past few days have mentioned the FBI recommending folks restarting their routers to avoid “Russian” malware from affecting some 500,000 routers.

This made me curious; what could restarting the router do to stop malware? Is this because Internet routers typically have software that checks for updates every time you restart them, and the ISPs and/or router manufacturers have issued patches to address a vulnerability, or is there something more interesting going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: It erases the volatile memory, which is where the plug-ins are stored that you're referring to. This was what was doing the heavy-lifting of the malware.

To fully get rid of malware, you are correct that the router's firmware will need to be upgraded or wiped and re-installed, but the malware referenced here  used various plug-ins that lived in and used the volatile parts of memory, similar to the RAM. This means a simple reboot killed whatever plugin was in use, but did not totally disinfect the router.

Check [here](https://www.thedailybeast.com/exclusive-fbi-seizes-control-of-russian-botnet) for a more in-depth explanation. Some important excerpts from the link include:

> Once in place, the malware reports back to a command-and-control infrastructure that can install purpose-built plug-ins, according to the researchers. One plug-in lets the hackers eavesdrop on the victim’s Internet traffic to steal website credentials; another targets a protocol used in industrial control networks, such as those in the electric grid. A third lets the attacker cripple any or all of the infected devices at will.

And:

> That allowed the bureau to identify a key weakness in the malware. If a victim reboots an infected router, the malicious plugins all disappear, and only the core malware code survives.